# Ruby On Rails Controller Tests, Factories or Mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, mocking

I'm relatively new to the testing part of rails. I've used unit testing in other languages. but with rails I have noticed those some examples using mocking to test controllers and others using factories, What is the best practise here?

Example using mocks: http://solnic.eu/2012/02/02/yes-you-should-write-controller-tests.html
Example using factories: http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html

In my research I've noticed this question: 
[Rails Model Testing - Mocking vs. Factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471760/rails-model-testing-mocking-vs-factories) 
Is the answer the same for controllers?

I am leaning towards mocking, mainly to speed things up and test in isolation, but I have seen comments that imply mocks cause tests to be brittle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocks are best at letting you isolate your tests.  If you're testing what messages your controller sends, which you probably are, there's no reason to send those messages to a real instantiated factory created object.  You can send them to a mock.

Also if you look at the second example.  Mostly what you're doing with factories is using them to generate a valid set of attributes to send to a POST or UPDATE request.  Using attributes_for not the whole object anyway.

One of the really interesting things I found that struggling with this kind of question about controller testing did for me, was highlight how the traditional way we build and use our Rails controllers is sometimes flawed and encourages a lot of very non-OO practices.

An example of an alternative approach is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGN4RFkhH2M 
This would be very easily tested using mocks and following Sandi Metz's approach laid out in Practical Object Oriented Design in Ruby - and this talk: http://www.confreaks.com/videos/2452-railsconf2013-the-magic-tricks-of-testing

I include the two links as you appear to be keen to learn more on the topic.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful response! just viewing those now. any suggestions on migrating from factory to mock without destroying my tests?

Comment: so i went to look at some controller test code of my own - i use things like ```let(:valid_attrs) { email: some@email, name: "somename" }``` instead of ```FactoryGirl.attributes_for```

Comment: also as to refactoring away from factories - like a lot of refactorings sometimes stepping back and inlining things is a good way to change direction - so step back from factories to actually creating the objects then from there should be easy to refactor those objects out for mocks, stubbing only the methods you need to stub ...remember controllers are for passing messages about and assigning variables for the view so really you will mostly be testing messages

Comment: other encouraged refactorings or design choices that will make your testing easier include using presenters/view_models which reduce further complexity away from your controller into easily testable POROs

Comment: On a side not discovered factorygirl has a build_stubbed method: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-factory-girls-build-stubbed-for-a-faster-test

Comment: The linked videos are both great, and I'd recommend them to anyone who wants to fast-forward their Ruby/Rails learning process. Even if you don't use or completely agree with the particular tools and techniques described in the presentations, they still provide a good overview of the sort of issues working programmers are grappling with, and the state of thinking in the Ruby community or "hive mind." Good stuff.